# Cannot get Beautifulsoup to recognize tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib

This simple scanner depicted below is designed to find the tag which displays a stock's percent change for the day on yahoo finance. When I examine the source code of the webpage I can easily identify that there is only one span tag which has a class equal to what I have written below. The tags class either reads $dataGreen if the price has gone up, or $dataRed if it has gone down.

I am using iterators in many other places on this webpage, all are formatted exactly the same way, and are functional. But for some reason, no amount of tweaking here will give me a result. It is as though this tag cannot be detected.

I haven't a clue why this tag can be found by `ctrl+f` but not `.find_all()`

Any guidance you can give me would be most appreciated. Here's my code.

```
import bs4 as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.request, urllib.error


url = str('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ABEO?p=ABEO')
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=30).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')


for row in soup.find('span',{"class":"Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataGreen)"}):
    print (1)
for row in soup.find('span',{"class":"Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataRed)"}):
    print (2)
```

Edit:

I've saved the source to a .txt and poured through it for the tag, though I couldnt detect it with `ctrl+f`either. When I compare what I found in the .txt to what I had pulled from the webpage, it differs. My problem seems to be solved, but I would love for someone to explain why that worked.

```
Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Fz(14px) C($dataRed)
```

Comment: Is that element generated by JS? Have you tried other html parsers?

Comment: I don't know know to tell if it is generated by JS, and this is the only parser I have used thus far.

Comment: Try writing the `source` to a txt file and inspecting it with a text editor to see if you can find the element. Also, I have good luck with `html.parser` if  `lxml` doesn't work.

Comment: Rodger. I'll give that a go

Comment: I can't find those *exact* class values in the source text. What data values are you wanting to extract? Is it you want a list of the stock's percent change for the day, one list of `dataGreen` for the increases and another list of `dataRed` for the decreasing values? Also, `soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s)'})` might give you a list of interesting values to filter, including the second index: `soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s)'})[1].text` which seems to return the percent change for the day.

Comment: hey thanks davedwards that does the trick!